# Im trying to install freeswitch on amazon linux Ami server.During make im getting the following error :

Tags: freeswitch

```
    /usr/bin/ld: ../../libs/libedit/src/.libs/libedit.a(term.o): undefined reference
    /usr/bin/ld: note: 'tgetnum' is defined in DSO /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 so try addin
    /lib64/libtinfo.so.5: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[5]: *** [fs_cli] Error 1
    make[4]: *** [/usr/src/freeswitch/libs/esl/libesl.so] Error 2
    make[3]: *** [mod_hash-all] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Ive tried to export 'ltinfo' library and ive also set LDFLAGS to -ltinfo but that too dint work.Please help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error like you. You must install stable version.

```
git clone -b v1.2.stable git://git.freeswitch.org/freeswitch.git
```

and follow the instruction again.

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Linux_Quick_Install_Guide

It will work.